# No resource identifier found for attribute error when trying to compile xamarin android project

Tags: android, resources, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin to build an android application but I'm having this error every time I try to compile the application.

I've added my attrs.xml file to Resources/values, referenced my namespace like this: 
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/mynamespace" and added the property to the view.

What am I missing? I've seen several examples but all seem to be working ok.

The reference is all in lower letters to avoid errors. I've also tried removing the http://... part and changing the folder "res" for "lib". These changes make the app to compile but I'm unable then to get the value of the parameter.

Please, any help will be really appreciated.

Best regards.

Comment: Tried `xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto` and did you ensure, that the build action of the attrs.xml is set to `AndroidResource` ?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer to my problem. It seems that it's not necessary to keep the lower letters when referencing the package name so if your package name is "MyNamespace", instead of using:

```
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/mynamespace
```

you have to use:

> xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/MyNamespace

It works now!